# SOSL for External Object

Tags: sosl, lightning-connect, salesforce-connect, externalobjects

I have configured a Salesforce Connect relationship to an external data source using a custom Apex adapter. I am trying to configure one of the external objects to allow search.

I have selected the "Allow Search" checkbox on the external object and have created a tab for the external object. The profile I'm using has read access for the object.

Firstly, the external object is not appearing in the available objects for results.

Secondly, when I run a SOSL query against the external object in the developer console, I receive the error `entity type <External Object> does not support search`. Do I need to do anything beyond checking "Allow Search" on the external object?

Additionally, when I navigate to the external data source and select "Validate and Sync", the "Allow Search" setting stays checked. When I then click "Sync", the external object has the "Allow Search" setting unchecked. I am not seeing anythng in the documentation for `DataSource.Table` or `DataSource.Column` that allows for explicitly specifying that an external object should allow search. In my DataSource.Connection class, I have a `search` method defined.

For reference:

DataSource.Table documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_Table.htm

DataSource.Column documentation: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_Column.htm#apex_class_DataSource_Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error and resolved it.

I was missing the appropriate "Capability Enum" (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_DataSource_Capability.htm) value in the `getCapabilities()` method in my `DataSource.Provider`.

So I went from

```
override global List<DataSource.Capability> getCapabilities() {
    List<DataSource.Capability> capabilities = new List<DataSource.Capability>();
    capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.ROW_QUERY);
    capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.REQUIRE_ENDPOINT);
    return capabilities;
}
```

to

```
override global List<DataSource.Capability> getCapabilities() {
    List<DataSource.Capability> capabilities = new List<DataSource.Capability>();
    capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.ROW_QUERY);
    capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.SEARCH);
    capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.REQUIRE_ENDPOINT);
    return capabilities;
}
```

To round out what I learned here, the "Validate and Sync" button runs the Apex from the `DataSource.Connection` `sync()` method, while clicking the "Sync" button subsequently runs at least the Apex in the `DataSource.Provider` `getCapabilities()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Did You enable it to external Data Source as well?

> To include an external object in SOSL and Salesforce searches, enable
>   search on both the external object and the external data source.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits_external_objects.htm

Comment: Right now, since I'm using a custom Apex adapter, I'm simply doing a custom callout within the `search` method and parsing the response, so yes it should be supported. Of course unless something else is needed here that I'm not aware of.

Comment: To be clear as well, the `search` method is implemented similarly to this Salesforce documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_Connection.htm